# Using a function to find letters and words

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the answer of the number of letters/number of words... I'm having problems with the word counting.

Actually in here i only declare that a new word is if there is a space, tab, of a newline, but is still doesn't work..

This is my function:

```
int num_of_letters_words()
{
    int numberOfLetters = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    int userInput;
    int answer;
    printf("please enter your input:\n");
    while ((userInput = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (ispunct(userInput))
            continue;

        else if(userInput == '\n')
            continue;

        else if (userInput == ' ')
            continue;

        else if (iscntrl(userInput))
            continue;

        else if (userInput == ' ')
            ;
        else
           numberOfLetters++;

        if (userInput == ' ' || userInput == '\n' || userInput == '\t')
            numberOfWords++;
    }
    answer = numberOfLetters/numberOfWords;
    return answer;
}
```

Only in the end of the function you can see the words counter... What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` makes your loop to continue with next iteration, it skips what follows it.

Let's say that "word" will be defined as a sequence of letters followed by delimiter (space, tab, etc.), then your loop could look like this:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || etc.)
    {
        if (letterCountThisWord > 0)
            wordCount++;
        letterCountThisWord = 0;
        continue;
    }
    letterCount++;
    letterCountThisWord++;
}

if (letterCountThisWord > 0)
    wordCount++;
```

If you're not sure about what's going on in your application, there are many great IDEs providing nice debugging tools. You can go through your code step by step, watch how your variables change and truly understand your code that way.

And one more advise: put something on your table (bottle, flower, etc.) and imagine it's your professor or boss and try to explain him in details how your code works. You will realize that you yourself have no idea about what some parts of your code actually do / what is going on, which will force you look for answers (google, books, ...).

Good luck :)

Comment: @Nir: You're welcome. We all were starting somehow :)

Comment: quick question - why is the if block that you wrote is not counting the control characters as words and add it to wordCount? from what it looks like is "if you see one of those cases, increment wordCount, and go to check the next character in the buffer...and of course i checked it and its work, so if i run the program and just do allot of spaces or newlines it returns 0, but from what it looks like it suppose to increment them. can you please explain to me what i miss here? :) @LihO

Comment: you got that right :) I Dont wat to count them. but if you can be kind enough to explain to me how come is this line "if (c is ' ' || '\t' || '\n' || ',' || '.' etc. )
    {
        wordCount++;
        continue;
    }" counting the words correctly...i dont understand, cause it looks like that every newline or tab(etc) it will decrement wordCount by 1...and if i run it and click only new lines and tabs for instance, and asking for the wordcount value, it is zero...which is what i wanted to do! but i wanted to understand how come..thanks! @LihO

Comment: @Nir: I just wanted to give you some hints that will direct you to the right direction, I thought you will finish it on your own. But since you seem to be kinda stuck with it, I edited my answer.

Comment: cool thanks :) what i did was if (isspace(userInput))
        {
            numberOfWords++;
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfLetters++;
        } @LihO